# Jmeter - Execute code based on Response assertion result

Tags: jmeter, conditional-statements, assertion

Trying to put some conditional logic in a script to only execute certain steps based on successful validation of a response assertion.

My script:
Main execution thread

```
- Submit Http request
-- Response assertion code 200 (indicates request successfully submitted)
-- Response assertion contains string (I expect a specific string back if successful)
-- Json extractor (extract the string I tested for in the response for later use)
- Do a bunch of other stuff
```

My problem is that I only want to execute 'bunch of other stuff' if I get back the expected string (without it everything will fail anyway).

I need a conditional test to only execute if the second response assertion passed.

I've tried using `"${JmeterThread.last_sample_ok}"` but this gives me an error of `If controller: error while processing ... BAD CONDITION...expected true or false`

I'm assuming I've placed the 'if' at the wrong point, or just used the condition inappropriately.

Any advice?

UPDATE:

My script currently looks like this:

```
- If test record is version 0
-- Send http to version 0 api
--- Response code assertion 200
--- Response assertion message contains specific string
--- Json extractor to extract the data associated with the string
-- If "${JmeterThread.last_sample_ok}"
--- Do other stuff
```

I'm assuming I've placed the If containing 'last sample ok' at the wrong level, or that the fact there's a json extractor as the last previous step that that has upset things.

Comment: can you show your if controller ?

Comment: Updated main description

Comment: please show screenshot of component If Controller, not pseudo code. thx

Comment: Sorry UBIK, can't show screenshots. Separate system and employer is very twitchy about proprietary stuff (and I don't like job hunting!) :)

Comment: I updated my answer with the fox. Accept it if ok so that it helps others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a mistake in case. Code is "**case sensitive**".

Here is how [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) should be configured:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The example I'd copied from had the case wrong. Feel like I need a facepalm emoji on here!

Answer (score 0):

Condition should be like ***${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==true*** in If Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Condition should be like this ${__jexl3(${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}=="true",)} in If Controller